# FFMPEG Batch convert, then create folder

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Using this code is it possible for it run this code then create a folder with file name if folder already exits move same name to same folder?

```
for i in *.mkv;   
do name=`echo "${i%.*}.mkv"`;   
ass="ass='$name'.ass"; 
echo "$ass";   ffmpeg -i "$i"   -vf "$ass" anime2/"${i%.mkv}.mp4";
done
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Your sentence is hard to follow.

Comment: Sorry, once the file has been converted i want a directory created in the files name to put the file in to automatically example: 
IF filename( E.G: stargate01) directory doesnt exist create director with filename then move converted mp4 file to Stargate Directory 
IF filename (E.G: stargate01) exists move startgate01 to directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `mkdir -p` and avoid having to use `if`/`then`:

```
for i in *.mkv; do mkdir -p "${i%.*}" && ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf ass="${i%.*}.ass" "${i%.*}/${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

Comment: Will be testing this when i get home,  so with mkdir -p if i have 2 files let says stargate-01 and stargate-02 stargate-02 will go in the dir made for stargate-01 not create or replace the existing dir?

Comment: @BenOwen `stargate-02.mp4` will go into the `stargate-02` directory. No directories will be replaced.